# Tensorflow slim evaluation loop, How to compue the accuracy of a checkpoint? Substitute for Streaming Metrics?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-slim

I am using `slim.evaluation.evaluation_loop` as a separate process to evaluate the models I train. To get the metric update ops I use `streaming metrics`. My code looks like,

```
## Compute the metrics
names_to_values, names_to_updates = slim.metrics.aggregate_metric_map({
                                    'accuracy' : slim.metrics.streaming_accuracy(tf.to_int32(tf.argmax(test_predictions, 1)),test_labels),
                                    })


## Aggregate the metrics
summary_ops = []
for metric_name, metric_value in names_to_values.iteritems():
        op = tf.summary.scalar(metric_name, metric_value)
        op = tf.Print(op, [metric_value], metric_name)
        summary_ops.append(op)    



## Evaluation parameter setup
slim.get_or_create_global_step()

test_summary_dir = {test summaries directory}
eval_interval_secs = {test interval in seconds} # How often to run the evaluation.
num_examples = {test set size} 
batch_size   = {test batch size}
num_batches  = math.ceil(num_examples / float(batch_size))


slim.evaluation.evaluation_loop(
        master="",
        checkpoint_dir={checkpoint directory name},
        logdir=test_summary_dir,
        num_evals=num_batches,
        eval_op=names_to_updates.values(),
        summary_op=tf.summary.merge(summary_ops),
        eval_interval_secs=eval_interval_secs,
        )
```

My question is, when using `streaming metrics`, Tensorflow keeps accumulating the metrics overtime. This means the earlier checkpoint accuracies are also accounted. This is not right if we need to evaluate a particular checkpoint.

Is there a way to reset the evaluation accuracies after every epoch in this explained setup ?

Or else, is there any other metric computation method other than `streaming_metrics` to work around this?

Thank you in advance!